# If $x,y$ are elements of $\emptyset$, $x+y$ is also an element of $\emptyset$. Does this statement unconditionally have meaning?

Tags: logic

> Statement 1:
> If $x,y$ are elements of $\emptyset$, $x+y$ is also an element of $\emptyset$.

Let $V$ be a vector space.
If we think $\emptyset\subset V$, then I think the above statement is not nonsense because we know that "$+$" is addition on $V$ and the above statement is vacuously true.

Let $S$ be a set whose elements are a banana, an orange, and an apple.
If we think $\emptyset\subset S$, then I think the above statement is nonsense because we don't know what "$+$" is on $S$.

Does Statement 1 unconditionally have meaning?
Is Statement 1 unconditionally true?

Comment: A case of the vacous truth , since the empty set has no elements.

Comment: @Peter Thank you very much for your comment. I think we don't know what "$+$" is.

Comment: What do you mean by a statement having meaning "unconditionally"?

Comment: Your question seems to boil down to whether or not we allow for statements like "*If `false==true` then `MAlfOrmEDexpREsSION`.*"  I for one would advocate against having malformed expressions in a statement, even if the truth of the statement does not rely on the expression.  As for what "+" means, it is usually clear from context.  Pick the first "+" that would make sense to work in the context, be it addition of integers, addition of reals, addition of matrices, etc...  and only adjust which "+" we are interpreting it to be if we find it doesn't work for our statement.

Comment: This is similar to how if we encounter the number "$2$" in a statement, we freely switch between $2$ the natural number, $2$ the integer, $2$ the real number, $2$ the complex number and so on... depending on context.

Comment: @5xum if I read Statement 1, I want to ask what "$+$" is. If we add condition $\emptyset\subset V$, then I know what "$+$" is. It is addition on a vector space $V$.

Comment: Whether a proposition is meaningful is not, by itself, an answerable question. A common way to interpret "valid" formulae is as well-formed formulae in some formal logic. Importantly, the logic must be chosen in advance, and it will declare what the valid symbols are and how they can be used. Normally (I claim) the function symbols (which take arguements) are not typed - every constant value in the logic is an admissible input. But I am sure there are logics where the function symbols can only be applied if some type constraints are met.#

Comment: Depending on your choice of formal system, the sentence you give is either well-formed and vacuously true, or syntactically invalid. It depends on your formal system.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you very much for your comments.

Comment: @5xum Thank you very much for your comment.

Comment: @preferred_anon Thank you very much for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer:**

The string of characters "If $x,y$ are elements of $\emptyset$, $x+y$ is also an element of $\emptyset$" is only a statement if the context in which the string is written makes it clear what the character "$+$" means.

If the meaning of the character is unknown, then the string above is not a statement at all (in other words, it is an "undefined" statement, or as you would put it, it is a statement that is a statement that does not have an unconditional meaning).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an application of the principle of vacuous truth:

> $\neg A \implies [A\implies B]$, a tautology for any logical
> propositions $A$ and $B$

[image]

Source: https://www.erpelstolz.at/gateway/TruthTable.html

While the implication $A\implies B$ must be true, it is not enough in itself to infer anything about the truth value of proposition $B$ since the antecedent $A$ is assumed to be false $(\neg A)$. $B$ could be true or false.

In your example, you have $A \equiv x\in \emptyset \land y\in \emptyset$ (always false) and $B \equiv x+y \in \emptyset$ assuming $x+y$ is well-defined.

Comment: Dan Christensen, Thank you very much for your answer.